# How can I clear firebase information in the keychain?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to clear firebase authentication credentials stored in the iOS keychain, but preferably not programmatically. Is there a way to do this in iOS settings without completely factory resetting the device? The issue stems from the fact that firebase authentication credentials are not cleared from the iOS keychain when an app that uses it is uninstalled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot access key chain items from the App Settings.

Yes, key-chain items will remain in the key chain when you uninstall the app.

There are situations when this has to be the case, for example when different apps share the same key chain items. As long as there are apps installed on the device which share the same items, you don't want them to be cleared.

Then, the less clear situation arises when your app is the only one on the device that can access the key chain items. Sometimes, we want the key chain items to remain there after deinstalling the app - and sometimes not. The current behaviour in iOS is, that they are not deleted - even when the key chain items are not shared. The documentation is a bit vague here, and I believe it was by accident that the items will not be cleared with the last app sharing them.

So, in order to clear key chain items, you need to do it from within an app which has access to the key chain items. That might be a certain app that happens to share the same keys - or the original one.

For more information: [Sharing Access to Keychain Items Among a Collection of Apps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps)